# rescuing active record : Record Invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my code.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :price, :released_on
begin
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  render( inline: "RESCUED ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid" )
  return
end
def self.to_csv(options = {})
CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
  csv << column_names
  all.each do |product|
    csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
  end
end
end



def self.import(file)
CSV.foreach(file.path , headers:true) do |row|
Product.create! row.to_hash   # If we want to add a new item

end
end
end
```

when I save a duplicate model with same name an exception is raised

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in ProductsController#import

```
Validation failed: Name has already been taken

Rails.root: /home/deepender/396-importing-csv-and-excel/store-before
```

I am using rescue operation still it is not handling error? Any guesses where I am wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Couple things. You don't wrap your `validates` in `begin/rescue` blocks. So your model should only look like:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :price, :released_on
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

And its in the controller where you perform the validation and handle it appropriately. A sample controller might look like:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])
    if @product.valid?
      @product.save
      flash[:notice] = "Product created!"
      redirect_to(@product) and return
    else
      render(:action => :new)
    end
  end
end
```

And then in your view you might render the actual errors back to the user:

```
# app/views/products/new.html.erb

<%= error_messages_for(@product) %>
.. rest of HTML here ..
```

`error_messages_for` is no longer included in Rails by default and its in the gem `dynamic_form`

For a generic method of displaying errors see this Rails Guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views

Comment: Actually my controller don't have create method , basically in this application I am importing CSV file and creating a database. Kindly see the updated code above.

Answer (score 3):

As Cody mentioned, do not wrap you valites in begin/rescue, because the validates method is just telling your model what need to be validated, it's not where the actual validation method is running.

Then, here's what your import method should look like :

```
def import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path , headers:true) do |row|
  product = Product.new(row.to_hash)

  if product.save
    # product valid and created 
  else
    # invalid record here... you can inspect product.errors
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks , i got one error saying that render method is not defined .    def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path , headers:true) do |row|
      @product=Product.new(row.to_hash)
      if @product.valid?
         @product.save
         flash[:notice] = "Product created!"
        redirect_to(@product) and return
    else
      render(:action => :index)        
  
    end
  end
end

Comment: Yes, it looks like you just took my controller code and plopped it into your code. The context of my code is a Rails Controller which has `redirect`, `render`, `flash`. You are not running inside a controller hence you have no access to those methods. Take a step back and think about what we have written and what your context is. It looks like you're not seeing the bigger picture.

Comment: Yep.In fact, you can remove the if part in my code and just write product.save Then, in a controller where you receive the file or w/e, you would need to call Product.import(file_uploaded) and there render based on the result of that call